# C#, How to running Hessian on IIS 5 (guide)

Tags: c#

Step 1
Q1) install VS.Net , but IIS not running the .ASMX file

A1 : try running C:\WINNT\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.0.2914\ aspnet_regiis.exe, parameter -i

aspnet_regiis.exe -i

this will install fresh APS.net running eveniroment to IIS

Step 2

Q2)

if you use HessianIISServerTest.zip you have to add this service to IIS.
Put the content of this ZIP-file (HessianServerTest) in "wwwroot" directory of IIS.
On my machine: c:\Inetpub\wwwroot.
Now go to "Internet Information Services" and select HessianServerTest.
Right Click and Select Properties. Select Virtual Directory and click on Configuration. You will see all extensions.
Click on Add and give executable path and new extension and click OK.
On my machine:
executable path: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll
extension: .hessian

Close IIS and Run your Client by using the URL:
String url = "http://localhost/HessianServerTest/HessianService.hessian";

For more details read this article:
http://www.csharpfriends.com/articles/getArticle.aspx?articleID=392&page=2

Step 3

IIS->choose the web app -->Property

check 'Virtual Directory'

add Extension to handle the hessain

executable path: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll
extension: .hessian

Notice : uncheck the option 'Check that file exist' or else it will not call the related service of the Hessian